# how to implement search directly from server

Tags: java, android, search

I want to implement search directly from the data on server. For example search from google.com. A edittext, like in search bar of google a word in edittext then it hits the server and fetch the records starting from that  word.

```
public class SearchActivity extends Activity {
TextView imeino;
Spinner select;
EditText searchby;
StringBuffer URL;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
    imeino = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.getimeino);
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String device_id = tm.getDeviceId();
    imeino.setText(device_id);
    searchby = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
     //this is a spinner if i choose mobile from this then edittext only takes numeric value.and if a select name then it takes alphabets.
    select = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    select.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            if(select.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Mobile"))
            {
                searchby.setInputType(InputType.     TYPE_CLASS_PHONE|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PHONETIC);

            }
            if(select.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("name"))
            {
                searchby.setInputType(InputType.   TYPE_CLASS_TEXT|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PERSON_NAME);

            }
            if(select.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Address"))
            {
                searchby.setInputType(InputType. TYPE_CLASS_TEXT|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_POSTAL_ADDRESS);

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {


        }
    });
this is my edittext in which i have to search for data

    searchby.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            searchby = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            String getitemforsearch = searchby.getText().toString();
            SearchFromCustomerData(getitemforsearch);               
            }

        public void SearchFromCustomerData(String getitemforsearch) {
            String searchType= new String();
            if(select.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Mobile"))
                {
                    searchType= "CustomerMobile";                       
                }
                if(select.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Address"))
                {           
                    searchType= "CustomerAddress";                      
                }
                if(select.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("name"))
                {
                    searchType= "CustomerName";
                }
```

This is my url to hit web service and it will show options

```
URL = new     StringBuffer("?"+searchType+"=" +     getitemforsearch+"&searchType="+searchType);
                    try {
                        URL sever = new URL(URL.toString());
                        System.out.println(URL.toString());
                        URLConnection yc = sever.openConnection();
                        InputStream in = yc.getInputStream(); // Get the data in the entity
                        InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(in);
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);
                        String read = br.readLine();
                        while (read != null) {
                                sb.append(read);
                                read = br.readLine();
                        }
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
                        JSONArray resultArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Customer");
                        System.out.println(" Length :" + resultArray.length());
                        String[] CustomerCode = new String[resultArray.length()];
                        String[] CustomerName = new String[resultArray.length()];
                        String[] CustomerEmail = new String[resultArray.length()];
                        String[] CustomerMobile = new String[resultArray.length()];
                        String[] Customeraddress = new String[resultArray.length()];
                        for (int i = 0; i < resultArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject object = (JSONObject) resultArray.get(i);
                            System.out.println("true");
                       CustomerCode[i] = object.getString("CustomerCode") == null ? "" :    object.getString("CustomerCode");
                       CustomerName[i] = object.getString("CustomerName") == null ? "" : object.getString("CustomerName");
                       CustomerEmail[i] = object.getString("CustomerEmailId") == null ? "" : object.getString("CustomerEmailId");
                       CustomerMobile[i] = object.getString("CustomerMobile") == null ? "" : object.getString("CustomerMobile");
                       Customeraddress[i] = object.getString("CustomerAddress") == null ? "" : object.getString("CustomerAddress");                                            
                        }                      
                                }
             catch (Exception e) {
            }
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
    }
    }
```

here is my layout file..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".SearchActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/getimeino"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:hint="ImEiNo..." />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/getimeino"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:entries="@array/process_arrays"
    android:prompt="@string/process_prompt" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/getimeino"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
 </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is unreadable in its current form, please fix the formatting and you may get help sooner.

Comment: I have tried to edit the language. Check it out now.

Comment: @Siddharth do you have any solution?

Comment: what does the code with `CustomerCode`, `CustomerName` etc have to do with Google search?

Comment: @Axarydax Customername and customercode are the field of my database,,i want to implement search like google not from google.like if we write android in google search bar it shows many option,same as that i want if anyone enter any thin in edittext it show options.

Comment: @AdrianBlackburn  do you have any solution of this problem.